# Prepending/appending hash keys in javascript / backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have a slight dilema.
This isn't general to backbone.js but it's certainly causing me issues getting the Backbone.Router.routes working:

The problem:
I have a bunch of hard coded routes in my js these follow a key value pair hash pattern like:

```
whatever.route : {"/url/goes/here":"functionNameHere"}
```

basically what this does is to bind a url to a function name to call when the URL is changed.

The problem I have is that I need to prepend the url with a lang/locale string so that the string would look like "/en/url/goes/here"

```
// this will always return "en" or "fr" or aany 2 letter language code    
var lang = window.location.pathname.split("/")[1].length ==2?window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]:false;


workspace = new Workspace( //Workspace is basically just a Backbone.router.extend Object
            {
                // the routes obj is basically a sequence of routes
                routes: {
                    "/":                    "home",
                    "/home":                "home",
                    "/terms":               "terms",
                    "/news":                "blog",
                    "/news/:title":         "blogpost",
                    "/about":               "about",
                    "/about/partners":      "partners",
                    "/about/people":        "people",
                    "/values/ethics":       "ethics",
                    "/values/innovation":   "innovation",
                    "/work":                "work",
                    "/work/process":        "process",
                    "/work/awards":         "awards",
                    "/work/:id":            "workdetail",
                    "/contact":             "contact",
                    "/contact/join":        "joinus",
                    "/contact/enquiries":   "enquiries"
                },
                lang : lang
            }
        );
```

my intial thought was along the lines of:

```
....routes{ lang+"/url/goes/here": "functionNameHere",
...
```

no dice errors
next i try using :

....routes{ eval(lang+"/url/goes/here"): "functionNameHere",
    ...

no dice again..

surely theres a way to dynamically prepend the hash key on the fly?

Anyone?

Thanks very much

**Solution Thanks to T.J. (see below)**

If anyone is interested in this in a Backbone.js specific way.
What I did was to use the solution T.J. suggested below on my initialize function like so:

Nice T.J.Crowder!!

not sure if I should edit the orig

```
initialize:  function(params){
        var tmpr = {};
        for(var i in params.routes)
        {
            tmpr[params.lang+i] = params.routes[i];
        }
        this.routes = tmpr;
......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part to the left of the `:` in an object literal *must* be a literal (either a token [e.g., without quotes] or a string literal [e.g., with quotes]). It cannot be an expression. So you can't do this in an object literal. Instead, you'll have to do this:

```
var routes = {};
routes[lang + "/url/goes/here"] = "functionNameHere";
// ...
workspace = new Workspace(
            {
                routes: routes,
                lang : lang
            }
        );
```

There, we're using the bracketed notation to assign properties to the `routes` object. When you use bracketed notation, you can use an expression to determine the property name. It's one of the cooler, and less-well-known, features of JavaScript that properties can be accessed either with dotted notation and a literal property name (`obj.foo`) or bracketed notation and a string property name (`obj["foo"]`). (In fact, that's what you're doing when you index into arrays — `a[0] = 5;` — because arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html).)